# How to parse data obtained from file generated by grep?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, grep

I've used "grep" to grab some data from a huge XML file. This is how part of the file looks like:

```
    <title>Hlavní strana</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
--
    <title>Nápověda:Jak vytvořit článek</title>
    <ns>12</ns>
--
    <title>Nápověda:Editace stránky podrobně</title>
    <ns>12</ns>
--
    <title>Astronomie</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
--
    <title>Biologie</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
```

Now I need to extract everything between "title" brackets that has the "ns" attribute of 0. I tried using regular expressions but it doesn't work. I really don't know how to parse a file like this one to get only what I want. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: suggestion: don't use `grep`... use `xml` module in python to work on original file itself.. or if you want from cli, use tools like `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best to use an **[XML parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.html)** on the original xml to get your required information. But to answer your question the below snippet might help.

**Demo**

```
s = """    <title>Hlavní strana</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
--
    <title>Nápověda:Jak vytvořit článek</title>
    <ns>12</ns>
--
    <title>Nápověda:Editace stránky podrobně</title>
    <ns>12</ns>
--
    <title>Astronomie</title>
    <ns>0</ns>
--
    <title>Biologie</title>
    <ns>0</ns>"""


import re
pattern = r"<title>(.*?)</title>\s+<ns>0</ns>"
print re.findall(pattern, s)
```

**Output:**

```
['Hlavn\xc3\xad strana', 'Astronomie', 'Biologie']
```

Comment: Thank you, I had problem with whitespaces - my regular expressions worked online, but not in my code, but this solved the problem!

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you tried, but regular expressions seemed to work pretty well for me:

```
import re

for title in re.finditer(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', data):
    print title.group(1)
```

But friends don't let friends parse XML type documents with regexes, as you can get in terrible difficulty with nested items and escaping. It's better to use a dedicated parser.

As you have already transformed the XML into something that isn't XML anymore, we'll have to use something that is tolerant of errors. HTML parsers are pretty good for this and we can use one called BeautifulSoup to do it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for title in soup.find_all('title'):
    print title.contents[0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! My regular expression worked online but not in my code, so I thought it doesn't work at all, but it had problem with whitespaces. Thank you for the tip, I will use it if it the other solution doesn't work well with my file.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a proper xml parser on the original data.

However, I want to draw your attention to awk as a grep-output parser. If you set the record separator (`RS`) to `--\n`, you can treat each match as a record. Here is a script that works with your example data:

```
awk -v RS='--\n' '/<ns>0<\/ns>/ { gsub(".*<title>|</title>.*", ""); print }'
```

Output:

```
Hlavní strana
Astronomie
Biologie
```